# Plain java project to be included in spring boot microservice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Got a class in common module(uses spring libraries but not spring boot) that I am injecting variables via constructor which takes Config class and RestTemplate class.

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Slf4j
public abstract class TokenGenerator {

    private Tokenonfig Tokenonfig;
    private String pingFedToken;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    protected TokenGenerator(Tokenonfig pingfedConfig, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.Tokenonfig = pingfedConfig;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
    ...
}
...Subclass below.....
@Component("idmTokenGenerator")
@Slf4j
@Getter
@PingFedHandler(type = PingfedType.IDM)
public class IdmTokenGenerator extends TokenGenerator {
    protected IdmTokenGenerator(PingfedConfig pingfedConfig, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        super(pingfedConfig, restTemplate);
    }
}
... Couldn't autowire. No beans of RestTemplate found....
```

I see the above error message and understand it since I am not creating RestTemplate bean in this common project. We create the beans in microservices which depends on this library. How do I resolve this by keeping this subclasses in the common module? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So are you looking for the correct dependency that contains the `RestTemplate` class? Or is the dependency there and just no `@Bean` to provide it?

Comment: No, this is not a spring boot app but present in the common library project. Will create the RestTemplate only in the spring boot app that uses this common library project.

Comment: but the code you showed is part of the library?

Comment: Yes it uses spring dependant jars but not a spring boot app

Comment: Nevermind I fixed this issue by not having a constructor based injection

Comment: "...not having a constructor based injection..." This sounds dangerous - do you inject that RestTemplate now field or setter based? Or don't you inject it at all?

Comment: field inject via setter method

Comment: It could be a sign of a circular dependency! You should check for this and resolve it. For constructor injection you could try to use the `@Lazy` annotation on the `RestTemplate` parameter. See also https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring